# cv2.putText русский текст

Tags: python, opencv

Добавляю текст на изображение таким образом

```
cv2.putText(img,'text',(10,round(height/2)), font, 4,(0,0,0),12,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Проблема в том, что если написать русские символы, текст превращается в вопросительные знаки.
Можно ли как то явно указать кодировку для putText?

Comment: А в шрифте, который вы используете, есть русские буквы? А то мало ли

Comment: В общем, покажите хотя бы что за font вы тут используете.

Answer (score 1):

попробуй указать fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, должно как то так выглядеть:

```
cv2.putText(img,'text',(10,round(height/2)), font, 4,(0,0,0),12,cv2.LINE_AA, fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX)
```